# Python Reapt value in specific Index Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking for a function in numpy to repeat a value at a specific index

```
index=3
newvalue=100
values=np.array([1, 2, 3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
values[0]=newvalue
value[1*index]=newvalue
value[2*index]=newvalue
value[3*index]=newvalue

#result [100, 2, 3,100,5, 6, 100, 8, 9, 100]
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index with a skip in a slice like this and set the values as you see fit:

```
index = 3
newvalue = 100
values = np.array([1, 2, 3,4,5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

values[::index] = newvalue
values
# array([100,   2,   3, 100,   5,   6, 100,   8,   9, 100])
```